# How to put python3 manage.py runserver in a Bash Script

Tags: python, django, bash, init.d, manage.py

Here is my Bash script it's very simple. I added it to the init/d folder so it works upon rebooting my computer. I create directories and so that part of the script is working; However my server won't run.
I'm trying to avoid having to type out:

sudo python3 manage.py runserver

...everytime I want to run my Django website; I want it to automatically start upon boot up.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#!/usr/bin/env python
# /etc/init.d/replicatorService

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          replicatorService
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

for i in {1..12}
do
    if [ ! -d "/media/drive$i" ]; then
    mkdir "/media/drive$i"
    fi
done

sudo python3 Documents/Replicator/dfp/dfp-rep/manage.py runserver
```

Comment: You should not do this. Use a proper server such as gunicorn.

Answer (score 0):

Remove sudo. ie

```
python3 Documents/Replicator/dfp/dfp-rep/manage.py runserver &
```

create a bash script with this. Say it is /root/run.sh

chmod +x run.sh

edit your /etc/rc.local
and add:
/root/run.sh

before the "exit 0" entry in the file.

Reboot should start your server.

However, it is not best practice. Use uwsgi to run the service.